# Modem won't respond

Tags: 12.04, modem, wvdial, fax

Modem will not respond in Efax-gtk or in Minicom after initialization.

This modem works fine in Windoze, SAME machine, just switched to Ubuntu 12.04 drive by mechanical switch.  I can go back and forth, always works in Windoze, never in Ubuntu.

Modem will attempt to answer an incoming call, but can't be sure about function since I don't have another modem to call with.

In minicom:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.5
OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on May  2 2011, 10:05:24.
Port /dev/ttyS4
Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

Nothing further will be shown, no matter what keyboard input, etc. - except it will respond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>, which are not modem responses

IN EFAX-GTK :

```
efax-0.9a: 21:27:23 opened /dev/ttyS4
```

Then try to send and wait 5 minutes - no result, so press "Stop":

```
efax-0.9a: 21:27:46 failed page /home/roger/Documents/Libre Office/Saddleback Labs Request.pdf.001
```

modem info `ttyS4`:

```
*-pci
description: PCI bridge
product: Integrated Technology Express, Inc.
vendor: Integrated Technology Express, Inc.
physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
version: 30 width: 32 bits clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pm subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
resources: ioport:d000(size=4096)
memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff

*-communication
description: Serial controller product: 56K FaxModem Model 5610
vendor: 3Com Corp, Modem Division
physical id: 1 bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
version: 01 width: 32 bits clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm 16550 cap_list
configuration: driver=serial latency=0
resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=8)

roger@roger-desktop:~$ sudo wvdialconf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0 S1 S2 S3
ttyS4<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyS4<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 115200 baud
ttyS4<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S5 S6 S7 S8
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S9 S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S17 S18 S19 S20 S21 S22 S23 S24
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S25 S26 S27 S28 S29 S30 S31
Sorry, NO MODEM WAS DETECTED! Is it in use by another program? - (my caps)
Did you configure it properly with setserial?
```

OK, so Ubuntu finds the modem, but doesn't find it!? Which is correct?

I'm almost ready to believe it's a kernel problem, except not by intent. I can't imagine anyone would intentionally screw that up thinking it's best for the world...

I'm NOT trying to connect to an ISP right now, I want to use it with eFax-GTK.

It worked on 12.04 before one of the later updates which included Ubuntu segments as well as others. Then it just quit.

Comment: I am a member of dialout group and all others I could think of that might affect this.

Comment: Have you tried to run `setserial`? Is there anything in the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: roger@roger-desktop:~$ sudo dmesg|grep tty
[sudo] password for roger:
[ 0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[ 1.365228] 0000:04:01.0: ttyS4 at I/O 0xd000 (irq = 17) is a 16550A
roger@roger-desktop:~$

Comment: sudo ls -al /dev/ttyS?
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS3
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 68 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS4
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 69 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS5
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 70 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS6
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 71 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS7
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 72 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS8
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 73 Dec 28 08:20 /dev/ttyS9

Comment: roger@roger-desktop:~$ sudo setserial -av /dev/ttyS4
[sudo] password for roger: 
/dev/ttyS4, Line 4, UART: 16550A, Port: 0xd000, IRQ: 17
 Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
 closing_wait: none
 Flags: spd_normal skip_test

roger@roger-desktop:~$

Comment: This problem has been recognized as a confirmed bug ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1087519 ), but there is no action on it for a LONG time  now...

Answer (score -1):

You can install software wvdial and gnome-ppp to using usb modem

sudo apt-get install wvdial && sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp

it so easy

Comment: I need to use the existing internal modem, just like Windoze does.  The external USB modem is not an answer for me.